# what's the purpose to use that in the javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I saw a style that use

```
var test = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.show() {
        that.***；
    }
}
```

I am wondering why use `that` in the function?

Comment: Its just a variable name, may be used to retain the value of `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of using `that` is to capture `this` in the context in which the function was constructed. When the function is called, `this` is in a different context (The caller I believe) so that when test() is called, `this` would not be what you expected it to be (unless you understand JavaScript, in which case it would be what you expect it to be, but not what you want it to be).

Answer (score 1):

To capture the correct value of `this`. JS's `this` semantics are a bit... funky, IMO.

What's "correct" depends on what you actually need, but `this` is evaluated late. In other words, `this`'s value during runtime may well be different than its value at function definition time. By capturing it at definition time you can ensure it's what you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `this` keyword is not persistent between functions in javascript. If you save it in a local variable using `that = this` it can be accessed from within the local functions regardless what context you apply to them.

```
var test = function() {
    console.log(this); // foo
    var that = this;
    var inner = function() {
        console.log(this); // bar
        console.log(that); // foo
    }
    inner.call('bar');
};

test.call('foo');
```